# error: nothing to repeat at position 0 for trying to remove rows containg "?" string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with these data frame and I am trying to remove any rows with the string "?", however whenever I do this I get the  error: nothing to repeat at position 0 but the code will work if I put any other number instead of ?

I also changed the whole data frame to strings.

```py
column_names = ["thick", "size_uni", "shape_uni", "marg_adh", 
                "size_epi_sieze", "bare_nuc", 
                "bland_chromo","norm_chromo", "mitosis", "outcome"]

data = data.astype(str)
for col_name in column_names:
    data[data[col_name].str.contains("?")==False]
```

Need to remove any rows containing ?, code works if i replace ? with any other number or letter

Comment: A regular expression is expected in which `?` has a special meaning. You can add argument `regex=False` to the `contains` call or replace `"?"` with `r"\?"`.

Answer (score 0):

The code iterates through each row. If any column has a `?`, it will be dropped.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['abc', 'ef?', 'hij'], # to remove
    ['klm', 'nop', 'qrs'],
    ['tuv', 'wxy', 'zzz'],
    ['abc', 'efg', 'hij'],
    ['klm', 'nop', '???'], # to remove
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for i, rows in df.iterrows():
    if any(['?' in col for col in rows]):
        df.drop(index=i, inplace=True)
```